# No Rule to make but the rule is there?

Tags: makefile

I created a make file (manually) to build my own OpenGL wrapper..

It keeps saying `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/Lin32/Exports.o', needed by 'bin/OpenGL32.so'.  Stop.`

However, the rule is: `$(ObjLinSRC)/$.o: $(SrcDIR)/%.cpp` where `ObjLinSRC = obj/Lin32` and 
`SrcDIR = src`..

What could be wrong with my make file? Doing `make windows` works perfectly fine but doing `make linux` fails.. I don't understand why. Any ideas?

```
WinGPP = g++
LinGPP = g++

BinDIR = bin
ObjDIR = obj
SrcDIR = src
BitFLG = -m32
WinOUT = OpenGL$(subst -m,,$(BitFLG)).dll
LinOUT = OpenGL$(subst -m,,$(BitFLG)).so
WinDIR = $(BinDIR)
LinDIR = $(BinDIR)
ObjWinSRC = $(ObjDIR)/Win$(subst -m,,$(BitFLG))
ObjLinSRC = $(ObjDIR)/Lin$(subst -m,,$(BitFLG))

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

WinDEP = -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -shared -s -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup -o
LinDEP = -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -shared -s -o

WinARGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -O3 -DOPENGL32_EXPORTS -s -c $(BitFLG)
LinARGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -O3 -DOPENGL32_EXPORTS -s -c $(BitFLG)


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CppFiles = \
    $(wildcard $(SrcDIR)/*.cpp)

ObjLinFiles = \
    $(patsubst $(SrcDIR)/%.cpp,$(ObjLinSRC)/%.o,$(CppFiles))

ObjWinFiles = \
    $(patsubst $(SrcDIR)/%.cpp,$(ObjWinSRC)/%.o,$(CppFiles))



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

all:
    @echo
    @echo "  Instructions For Making GLX:"
    @echo
    @echo "    For Windows:     make windows"
    @echo "    For Linux:       make linux"
    @echo "    For Both:        make both"
    @echo "    To Clean Files:  make clean"
    @echo "    Specific Builds: BitFLG=-m32 | BitFLG=-m64"

both: linux windows

linux: $(LinDIR)/$(LinOUT)
    @echo
    @echo "Finished Building OpenGL32 -- Colour-Only."

windows: $(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT)
    @echo
    @echo "Finished Building OpenGL32 -- Colour-Only."

clean:
    @echo "    Cleaning Build Files."
    @rm -rf $(BinDIR) $(ObjDIR)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



$(LinDIR)/$(LinOUT): $(ObjLinFiles)
    @echo
    @echo "Linking Linux Object Files.."
    @mkdir -p $(LinDIR)
    @$(LinGPP) -fPIC -shared $(LinDEP) $(LinDIR)/$(LinOUT) $(ObjLinFiles) $(BitFLG)

$(ObjLinSRC)/$.o: $(SrcDIR)/%.cpp
    @echo "    Compiling Linux: "$<
    @mkdir -p $(ObjLinSRC)
    @$(LinGPP) $(LinARGS) -o $@ $<





$(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT): $(ObjWinFiles)
    @echo
    @echo "Linking Object Files.."
    @mkdir -p $(WinDIR)
    @$(WinGPP) -Wl,--kill-at -d --input-def $(SrcDIR)/OpenGL32.def $(WinDEP) $(WinDIR)/$(WinOUT) $(ObjWinFiles) $(BitFLG) -lgdi32 -lglu32 -lopengl32

$(ObjWinSRC)/%.o: $(SrcDIR)/%.cpp
    @echo "    Compiling: " $<
    @mkdir -p $(ObjWinSRC)
    @$(WinGPP) $(WinARGS) -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$(ObjLinSRC)/$.o: $(SrcDIR)/%.cpp
```

The `$` in `$.o` should be a percent:

```
$(ObjLinSRC)/%.o: $(SrcDIR)/%.cpp
```

Comment: Omg.. of all things -_-. It works now :D Thank you! I will accept as soon as it lets me.